# How find a dynamic id in html of page with scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying get text of a dynamically created ID of a html tag. I there any way I get it. Code is:

```
<p class="old-price">
    <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span>
    <span class="price" id="old-price-8886"> ৳300 </span>
</p>
```

here `id="old-price-8886"` is a dynamic ID. In this ID `"old-price-****"` is static for all `price` class. I need to get `৳300` value from it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming attribute selectors are supported you can use attribute = value selector with starts with operator to specify partial match.

```
[id^="old-price-"]
```

You can extend that to include parent classes, for example:

```
.old-price [id^="old-price-"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you wouldn't use that id at all, and would use the classes to get the data:

```
>>> sel.css('.old-price .price::text').get()
' ৳300 '
```

If that's not a possibility, you can use `starts-with` with either xpath or css:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//span[starts-with(@id, "old-price-")]/text()').get()
' ৳300 '
>>> sel.css('span[id^="old-price-"]::text').get()
' ৳300 '
```